# Why does 2+2 equal to 4?

Tags: soft-question, definition, foundations

The question is in the title. I am very appreciative of any time and concern put into belaboring this relatively little problem.

Comment: Can we assume that $1+1 = 2$?

Comment: Before this gets downvoted into oblivion, can you elaborate on your question? Is this more of a philosophical question or ... ? (You need to add context; otherwise, your question will be closed)

Comment: You may read some classic text like Landau's Foundations of Analysis.

Comment: What is your definition of $4$? If your definition is that it's $2+2$, then you're done. If your definition is that it's $3+1$, then we go further: what is your definition of $1$? Of $2$ and $3$? Of $+$? When you ask such basic questions, you need to go this deep down into the matter in order to prove anything.

Comment: 2+2=4 only when the Party says it does.

Comment: $2+2\equiv 1 \bmod 3$. $2+2=1$ within $\mathbb Z_3$. Definition and context are important.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html

Comment: @MarkBennnet But at the same time, $2+2\equiv 4\pmod 3$, so the premise isn't wrong in that case either.

Comment: I've heard engineers say that 2+2=5 for extremely large values of 2.

Comment: @MarkBennet Good point.  In any monoid you can choose any element to call "1" and then 2 is simply defined to be $1+1$ and 3 is defined to be $1+1+1$ etc.  In every case $4=2+2$.

Answer (score 2):

The *definition* of 2 is $1+1$.  The definition of 4 is $1+1+1+1$.  In general any $n$ is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^n1$.  You can think of that as a purely abstract symbol.  And the sum $n+m$ is defined to be $\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}1$.  It is easy to show that this set and addition make this a well defined monoid.  Then you must simply show that $(1+1)+(1+1)=1+1+1+1$.  This is  true because addition, as defined, is associative.

Comment: Hmmm. This seems like a bit of a reductive answer. It also glosses over the fact that we are presumably computing sums in a base-10 system. I think it would be wise/appropriate to wait until OP clarifies the question.

Comment: @crash: the base isn't relevant, as long as by "$4$" you mean the number usually represented by that symbol and not the symbol itself (which you should).

Comment: @A.P. The base is certainly relevant. What is $2+2$ in base-3? It certainly isn't $4$.

Comment: @crash Where is the base ten? Anyways, base is irrelevant to the math itself, $10$ is just two squiggles and we have agreed that when they appear together, they should mean $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1$, to save space and improve readability. The fact that the first squiggle resembles $1$ is purely coincidental.

Comment: In any monoid you can choose any element to call "1" and then 2 is simply defined to be $1+1$ and 3 is defined to be $1+1+1$ etc.  In every case $4=2+2$.  That's total generality, true in any monoid.  Not necessarily true in a non-associative algebra.

Comment: All of you are proving my point made in my first comment--we should, all of us, **wait** until the OP provides context for the question. Otherwise, answers may be completely off-base (no pun intended but enjoyed).

Comment: @GregoryGrant how do you define $1+1+1+1$, though? Usually addition is defined as a binary operation first and then extended by, say, left associativity, in which case $1+1+1+1 := ((1+1)+1)+1$.

Comment: @A.P. Originally I was just thinking of it as an abstract symbol and defining addition on abstract symbols.  In the context of a monoid however, we are given associativity, so there is no ambiguity.